# Is it important to override Equals if I'm implementing IEquatable<T>?

Tags: c#, generics, equality, iequatable

I know the importance of overriding `GetHashCode` when implementing custom equality checks - for which I have implemented `IEquality<T>` interface, and also the difference between generic and non-generic `Equals` [as discussed here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476793/when-to-use-iequatable-and-why) Now is there a point to override `Equals(object t)`? Wouldn't everything come under generic `Equals(T t)`?

```
public override int GetHashCode() //required for hashsets and dictionaries
{
    return Id;
}

public bool Equals(T other) //IEquatable<T> here
{
    return Id == other.Id;
}

public override bool Equals(object obj) //required??
{
    return Equals(obj as T);
}
```

Comment: Watch out with your implementation there. In the generic version you should account for `other` being `null` as `obj as T` will result in null if `other` is not a `T`.

Comment: @Jamiec yes, this was just an example. I'm aware. Thanks

Comment: Great, glad you're aware. Was more thinking about future visitors which may see this question and assume that's the right way to implement `IEquatable<T>`, when its missing a vital part.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between IEquatable and just overriding Object.Equals()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734914/whats-the-difference-between-iequatable-and-just-overriding-object-equals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx):

> If you implement IEquatable, you should also override the base
>   class implementations of Object.Equals(Object) and GetHashCode so that
>   their behavior is consistent with that of the IEquatable.Equals
>   method. If you do override Object.Equals(Object), your overridden
>   implementation is also called in calls to the static
>   Equals(System.Object, System.Object) method on your class. In
>   addition, you should overload the op_Equality and op_Inequality
>   operators. This ensures that all tests for equality return consistent
>   results.

I could have done a better google search too. Here's a [good article on msdn blogs by JaredPar](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2009/01/15/if-you-implement-iequatable-t-you-still-must-override-object-s-equals-and-gethashcode.aspx) on the subject.

In short, overriding `Equals(object obj)`:

> Needed for the static *Equals(object obj1, object obj2)* method on *object* class, or for *Contains(object item)* on *ArrayList* instance etc..

Accepting this since the link is more thorough on the subject. Thanks to Oded too..

Answer (score 11):

Unsealed types should not implement `IEquatable<T>`, since the only way to ensure (or even make it likely) that derived types will implement it correctly is to implement `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)` so as to call `Object.Equals(Object)`.  Since whole purpose of `IEquatable<T>` is to avoid wasting CPU time converting things to `Object` before comparing them, an implementation which calls `Object.Equals(Object)` couldn't do anything faster than the default behavior that would be achieved if the interface wasn't implemented.

Sealed class types may achieve a slight performance advantage by implementing `IEquatable<T>`; the preferred style is to have `Object.Equals(Object)` try to cast the parameter to `T`; if the cast succeeds, use the `IEquatable<T>.Equals` implementation; otherwise return `false`.  In no case should `IEquatable.Equals(T)` and `Object.Equals(Object)` yield different results when passed the same object instance.

Structure types may use the same pattern as sealed class types.  The method of attempting the cast is a little different, since a failed cast can't return `null`, but the pattern should still be the same.  If a struct implements a mutating interface (as is the case with e.g. `List<T>.Enumerator`, a struct that implements `IEnumerator<T>`), the proper behavior of equality comparisons is a bit murky.

Note, btw, that `IComparable<T>` and `IEquatable<T>` should be considered independent of each other.  While it will often be the case that when `X.CompareTo(Y)` is zero, `X.Equals(Y)` will return true, some types may have a natural ordering where two things may be different without either ranking about the other.  For example, one might have a `NamedThing<T>` type which combines a `string` and a `T`.  Such a type would support a natural ordering on the name, but not necessarily on `T`.  Two instances whose names match but whose `T`'s differ should return `0` for `CompareTo`, but `false` for `Equals`.  Because of this, overriding `IComparable` does not require overriding `GetHashCode` if `Equals` is not changed.

Comment: excellent insight in general though not precisely on the question, +1-ed. I have a small doubt on your thoughts on iequatable being valid only for sealed types. Let me say I have `Person : IEquatable<Person>` unsealed which has its on `Equals` implementation which is just `return Id == other.Id` considering `Id` is a field on `Person` class. Now if I'm deriving `Person` to `Student`, and Student doesn't override anything, what's your point about performance loss, and also about non generic `Equals` being used again? Could you explain this with the above example in a lil more detail?

Comment: I'm thinking if `Student` has to be compared for equality, wouldn't the same `Equals` method on `Person` class be used again? Or you're saying the default non generic reference equality checking `Equals` of `Student` will be used?

Comment: @nawfal: If `Student` does not implement `IEquatable<Student>`, then a hashed collection of `Student` would use the virtual `Object.Equals(Object)` method.  If it does implement `IEquatable<Student>`, then it would have to either have such implementation chain to the base-class `IEquatable<Person>.Equals` method or hard-code its own copy of that method.  The former would negate any performance advantage of implementing `IEquatable<Student>`, and the latter would risk breaking things if the behavior of `IEquatable<Person>` changes.  The performance advantage of using `IEquatable<T>` on...

Comment: ...a struct type is often quite large.  The maximum achievable performance advantage with a class type is much, much, smaller.  Even a small performance gain in heavily-used code may be worth taking, if it won't require sacrificing <i>anything</i>, but limiting the behavior of derived classes doesn't seem like a win.  Further, I would think that a cleaner design might be to have a sealed type which contains an ID and an inheritable `PersonInfo` object, where the latter object's compare method would do a full comparison, and the former object would specify an invariant that...

Comment: ...two instances with the same ID must always hold references to `PersonInfo` instances that compare as equal to each other.  That would clarify the relationship between the IDs and the objects' contents, in a way which would continue to hold for derivatives of `PersonInfo` even if such derivatives add more fields.

Answer (score 7):

You certainly *should* override `Equals(object t)` - otherwise you may get incorrect results when that overload is used. You can't assume that the `Equals(T other)` is the overload that will be called.

If you don't override it, reference equality will be used, meaning that something like the following will return false:

```
myObject1.Id = 1;
myObject2.Id = 1;

myObject1.Equals((object)myObject2); // false!
```

Another possible problem is with inheriting classes - if you compare your type with an *inheriting* type, this can easily fail.

Comment: I'm asking when can non generic Equals be called? Then what's the point of generic Equals? Sorry this answer is not complete I feel

Comment: @nawfal - Added detail to my answer.

Comment: Ok I get it now. But the shown example is so rare, still I get the point.

Comment: @nawfal - The example was given to illustrate the possible issue.

Comment: @nawfal `Another possible problem is with inheriting classes - if you compare your type with an inheriting type, this can easily fail.` Why is that so? I'd have thought that Equal(T) would be called if you compare types which inherit of T.